# Can a "4 line" Grandstream GXP 2000 handle 8 lines?

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, telephony, trixbox

We have a whole bunch of GXP 2000 phones here but now we're growing too big for just 4 incoming lines. We use Trixbox (asterisk) for the phone system with 4 analog lines coming into a Dell server.

Is there a way that these Grandstream GXP 2000 phones can handle 8 lines? How does that work? Is there some kind of configuration that can be done in Trixbox when we do move to 8?

Answer (score 1):

The number of lines are the number of active calls on that *specific* phone extension, depending on the business you'll want to stick them in a queue like recommended before and distribute them to different people/departments.

In reality except for a receptionist, the use of more than two lines is usually worthless, and I'd usually stick them behind a queue (and probably a auto attendant...) too.

Comment: So what if someone calls from NYC, California, Minnesota, Iowa, and then another person calls? All have to go through receptionist before getting to our individual lines because they need to be screened first and people are always in and out of their offices (physically). Is there a guide somewhere for this "queue" process?

Comment: Add a queue using the Trixbox interface, give it an extension and make that the destination for inbound calls, add the receptionist to the queue as an agent. Though having multiple lines helps if the receptionist needs to put a lot of people on hold, park works well for this too. You can easily test this out by adding yourself to a queue with an extension and having another phone call it, the phone calling will hear music (or ringing, depending on how you configure it) and everyone as agents on the queue will have their phones ring (by whatever rule you apply).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Sn3zdiU2WY

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue and stack your incoming calls.

That way you can handle more than 4.